# Matrix formulation of the Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am confused on how to go about solving this exercise

[image]

In my lecture we started off from the discrete fourier transformed and then went into the FFT, but we were already in matrix form. Does anyone have ideas for this?

Comment: It asks to say $A$ is an [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) up to a constant, but honnestly you should read another course. See instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm

Comment: Those two links are what we discussed in the lecture which made sense then. Unfortunately this doesn't really help me answer the exericse.

Comment: This isn't an exercice, but the main theorem : that the DFT is an unitary matrix / linear transformation.

Comment: Mm...okay. I see how $A_ij$ describes exactly the DFT matrix, but I do not actually understand what $v = <f, E_j>_n$ denotes. How to actually build to the DFT matrix. I guess that is what the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm algorithms describes? I doubt i'm being asked to copy that though

Comment: No, you can look at the FFT algorithm only once you have understood the DFT perfectly

Comment: And it denotes the inner product of (complex) vectors : $\langle u,v \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k \overline{v_k}$

Comment: Sorry, I know the $<f,E_j>_n$ denotes the inner product I am just confused on how it related to this exercise. $f$, for the DFT, is the RHS of the system of equations (so constants) and $E_j$ is $e^{ijx}$ for each constant in the LHS of the sys of equations. How $<f,E_j> = Au$? I just don't really know how this inner product works for $f$ and $E_j$